# AspectJ: Thread name from joinPoint

Tags: java, aspectj

Is it possible to get/set thread name from joinPoint?

```
@Around("call(void methodA())")  
public Object conditionB(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
{   
    Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());  
    return res;
}
```

`Thread.currentThread().getName()` get name of thread `main` from AspectJ class. Is it possible to get (probably from joinPoit) name of thread which executes methodA?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the question, they are the same thread. In your example, main calls methodA and your advice is calling conditionB around the call to methodA. All this happens on a single thread.

Comment: @JohnWatts I see now. So is there any possible way to get name of thread witch started executing `conditionB`?

Comment: inside conditionB you can just call Thread.currentThread().getName(), if that's what you need

Comment: @Less As you can see in my example I tried to do that, but the result is not a thread which started executing conditionB.

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed it in the example. So, if I understand correctly, you spawned a new thread to execute conditionB, but you don't get the name of that thread within the conditionB?

Comment: @Less Actually your and mine solution works. I simply didn't notice that I had the same names. Everything works fine now. Thanks

Comment: yep :) that's why I always go with thread id's instead of names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `Thread.currentThread().getName()` works fine. It is name set in methodA. Just be careful with the same thread-names.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do that? Try to invoke the `methodA()` method from another thread.

I guess it's really possible.